# How select field work when we have multiple and we can choose only one second will b disable according to choose item

Tags: php, jquery

How to choose one field in select box if one will choose second one will be disable and if second one will choose than first one will be disable how it will work help me for that

```
<select>
</select>
```

or

```
<select>
</select>
```

Comment: If you are using <select> it will select by default one every time if you not using "multiple" attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="multiple">

</select>
```

Comment: not like this bro actually i want, one select field will work and other will disable from both  if i will choose any of them

Answer (score 0):

make a javascript function and call it when user select an option

```
someFunction = function(){
var yourSelect = document.getElementById('selectid')
var number = yourSelect.selectedIndex;
if number === 0{
    var x = yourSelect.options[number + 1].disabled = true;
}else if number === 1{
    var x = yourSelect.options[number - 1].disabled = true;
}}
```

assuming you have only two options here
in html code
`<select id = "selectid" onChange="someFunction()">`

Comment: actual bro i don't want to disable option i just want to disable complete select box while i have two select boxes

Comment: then just do this `yourSelect.disabled = true`